# Why I can't sideload my .appx file and why it's nowhere to be found?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, uwp, window, appx

My question is very simple and yet very complex. 
I need to side load my application's .appx file to SurfacePro (Microsoft tablet with windows10) but I cannot side-load it because there's nothing to side-load...

1. I've created a simple unity project and switched the build to Universal Windows Platform (UWP)
2. I've made sure I have the latest IIL2CPP on my machine and all the needed libraries on my VisualStudio 2017
3. I build the unity project in a dedicated directory - the build resulted with success and the directory had a solution file = .sln file.
4. I double clicked the .sln file and opened it in VS 2017
5. In VS2017 I chose "Master", "X86" and "local Machine" (I then tried "device" and "remote machine" this gave errors) and build worked!
6. I then saw my application's "made with unity" logo and the scene
7. I close the application using Alt+F4
8. I want to re-open the application but I can't find the file! I understand this is a file that need to be side-loaded to my machine, similarly to .apk files which loaded and installed on android devices
9. I can't find the .appx file

I understand that I need to run the build each time I need to open the application, is that true?

Comment: I have no experience with the Unity side of this... but to create the packages, you would right-click the Universal Windows project and choose Store-->Create App Packages.  I'm not sure if the Unity piece changes this or not.

Comment: @MarkW you're absolutely correct. This is what I did and now I have the .appx package

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  I made it an answer if you would please mark as such so if others come across the same question, it will be clear.

Answer (score 3):

I have no experience with the Unity side of this...

but to create the packages for a UWP application, you would right-click the Universal Windows project and choose Store-->Create App Packages.